# How to calculate the survey mean with a categorical auxiliary variable in R "survey"?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, prediction, survey-sampling

When I use a continuous auxiliary varaible in `svyglm`, I can predict the mean of the dependent variable from the mean of the auxiliary variable (MRE below). How do I do the same thing if my auxiliary variable is a categorical variable? I considered recoding the variable using effect coding (-1, 1) and then predicting from the value 0, but that makes no sense as this would simply eliminate the regression coefficient.

Incidentally, I'm also confused about why the continuous auxiliary variable gives a worse prediction than with no auxiliary variable. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something more general here.

### EDIT

Does the `svypredmeans` function do this? What is it doing behind the scenes, as in what is the math?

```r
### `svypredmeans`???
preds = 
  svypredmeans(dclus2_glm_awards, ~api00) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  pull(mean)

mu = mean(preds)
SE = sd(preds)/sqrt(length(preds)-1)

list(mean = mu, SE = SE)
#> $mean
#> [1] 700.2
#> 
#> $SE
#> [1] 13.08446
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
library(survey)
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: survival
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'survey'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     dotchart
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     set_names
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract

data(api)
### https://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/html/api.html

### Population Mean
mean(apipop$api00)
#> [1] 664.7126

### Sample Mean
mean(apiclus2$api00)
#> [1] 703.8095

### Survey Design
dclus2_dsgn = svydesign(id=~dnum+snum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus2)

### direct survey mean
dclus2_mean = svymean(~api00, dclus2_dsgn)
dclus2_mean
#>         mean     SE
#> api00 670.81 30.712

### Continuous Auxiliary Variable
dclus2_glm = svyglm(api00 ~ meals, design=dclus2_dsgn)
summary(dclus2_glm)
#> 
#> Call:
#> svyglm(formula = api00 ~ meals, design = dclus2_dsgn)
#> 
#> Survey design:
#> svydesign(id = ~dnum + snum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus2)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  821.707     25.710  31.961  < 2e-16 ***
#> meals         -2.872      0.420  -6.837 4.08e-08 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 8803.949)
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
 predict(
  dclus2_glm,
  newdata = apiclus2 %>% summarize(meals = mean(meals)),
  se.fit = T
)
#>     link     SE
#> 1 715.64 20.329
 
### Categorical Auxiliary Variable
dclus2_glm_awards = svyglm(api00 ~ awards, design=dclus2_dsgn)
summary(dclus2_glm)
#> 
#> Call:
#> svyglm(formula = api00 ~ meals, design = dclus2_dsgn)
#> 
#> Survey design:
#> svydesign(id = ~dnum + snum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus2)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  821.707     25.710  31.961  < 2e-16 ***
#> meals         -2.872      0.420  -6.837 4.08e-08 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 8803.949)
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
### How to predict mean? ###
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: From the documentation "Predictive marginal means for a generalised linear model, using the method of Korn and Graubard (1999) and matching the results of SUDAAN. The predictive marginal mean for one level of a factor is the probability-weighted average of the fitted values for the model on new data where all the observations are set to that level of the factor but have whatever values of adjustment variables they really have."  You can see all the math in this paper:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.0006-341X.1999.00652.x?sid=nlm%3Apubmed

Comment: Is it really that complicated to predict a mean with a dichotomous auxilliary variable while it's so straightforward with a continuous one?